# Database Default Column

Tags: database, default

just a quick question regarding the Database Structure.
I have to manage several roles but there needs to be only one default role, which is User automatically is assigned to.

How would you store this default tole in the DB? Something like that?

```
ID     |   Name   | IsDefault
-----------------------------
1      |   Admin  | no
2      |   User   | yes
```

If so, how can you check that only one role is marked as default?

Thanks

Comment: What RDMS do you use? For example, in Oracle you can have function-based unique index, SQLServer let's you define filtered unique index...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Oracle you can have for instance, check constraint on `IsDefault` column, so it can be just `yes` or `no`. Then

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDXU_TABLE1_ISDEFAULT ON table1(CASE WHEN IsDefault ='yes' THEN IsDefault ELSE NULL END);`

Comment: thats clear, I want to check whether all Roles just contain a single default value.

Comment: Unique index won't let you insert/update record so you won't have 2 rows where isDefault = 'yes'. Is it not what you want ? Sorry, if I misunderstood the question. You can have as many rows where `IsDefault = 'no'`, but just one where it's 'yes'...

Comment: Ok then I misunderstodd you, Im sorry. solved my problem thanks!